# Select infos in sub-divs with jQuery

Tags: jquery, screen-scraping

I am a member of Safaribooksonline.com and I love it.

Now I would like to save a list of the books that I have in my library.

If I look at the html-source of the books list, I have divs like [1] below within the class "main".

I loaded jQuery into the browser console and then selected all "main" divs with `books_list = jQuery(".main")`. This gives me an Object with entries like `Object { 0: <div.main>, 1: <div.main>  ...`.

I can iterate over these entries and extract the sub-infos (book title etc).

What is the most idiomatic way to get the sub-divs and sub-infos from these main divs? Ideally in JSON format. So that I have `{title: "book title", author: "book author", etc}`

---

[1] Divs containing book infos

```
<div class="main">
  <span class="cover">
    <a href="/library/view/learning-javascript-design/9781449334840/">
      <span><img src="/library/cover/9781449334840/"></span>
    </a>
  </span>

  <a href="/library/view/learning-javascript-design/9781449334840/" class="next title-block js-bit-title t-bit-link">
    <span class="chapter-title t-bit-title">Learning JavaScript Design Patterns</span>
  </a>
  <span class="book-title">
    <span class="author">by Addy Osmani</span>
    <span class="issued">Released: August 2012</span>
  </span>

  <div class="t-read-link prog-text">
    <a href="/library/view/learning-javascript-design/9781449334840/index.html" class="button position-link t-position-link js-position-book">Start reading now</a>
  </div>

  <div class="book-topics">
    <ul class="topic-display">
  <li><a href="/topics/design-patterns" class="topic t-t-link" data-topic-slug="design-patterns">Design Patterns</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [$().each](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

> Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element.

E.g.:

```
jQuery(".main").each(function() {
    // do something with each div, access them using $(this)
});
```

Comment: Thanks! And how do I access for instance the span with class `book-title`? Is it with `$(this).childNode`? Sorry, I'm very new to jQuery and the DOM

Comment: You can go "deeper" using `$(this).children().each(function() {});`

Comment: You would do `$(this).find('.book-title')`